# Connecting Vcc pin to a logic gate

Tags: grounding

I have a sonar sensor which has 4 pins and may be due to a bug in my code, they are freezing in a few seconds after functioning. I found out if I reconnect the Vcc pin, they start working and yeah they freeze again. So I'm thinking rather than unplugging and plugging in the Vcc pin, to use an inverter (NOT gate) to activate it when I need the sonar to work and disable it whenever I don't need it. With an inverter we are setting ground voltage as we are disabling and I wonder if it would harm the sensor circuit by any mean.

Comment: Since we don't know what the sensor is supposed to do, any attempt at figuring out what the four pins are for would be mostly guesswork. How about if you post a description of your application and a  data sheet for the sensor or, at the very least, a description and a link to the data sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Y-yZnNhMYy7rwhAgyL_pfa39RsB-x2qR4vP8saG73rE/edit It is an HC SR04 Ultrasound sensor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no other input pins on the device, I don't see how setting the VCC pin to ground would cause any problem.  However, will the NOT gate provide enough output current to operate the device?  Note that many devices can draw power from input pins (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yFh7Vv0Paw) and continue working even in the absence of a VCC connection.  But pulling VCC low while other inputs are connected may cause excessive current or damage.

Comment: Could your freeze-ups be caused by noisy power?  Have you tried some filtering caps on the VCC rail near your sonar device?

Comment: I didn't use any capacitors. I'm thinking about using a CMOS Inverter 4009. There are 3 sensors and I think that is not a good idea to use a logic gate to drive this sensor right? Is there any other options? I'll try connecting a capacitor between Vcc and Ground pins of the sensor and see if the issue is gone :)

Comment: Why not just use a transistor to switch the VCC pin instead of a gate?

Comment: That's what I'm thinking :)

Comment: Can I use a darlington array to switch the circuits here?

Comment: Do you need a Darlington?   How much current is drawn by the device?  Will a simple PNP transistor do the trick? (2N2907 or similar)

Comment: It draws 15 mA. Darlington is new to me. So that's why I was thinking about using that just to get an experience with them :) But from what I saw darlington acts as a switch to the ground pin right? So I better use a transistor :)

Comment: A Darlington is just an array of transistors to allow switching larger load currents with smaller control currents.  (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darlington_transistor).  You are referring to the type of transistor: NPN vs PNP.  Please check out this nice tutorial regarding switching the ground or supply voltage.  To switch the input supply, use a PNP transistor. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNVaIqmKUoI)

Comment: The 2N2907 handles up to 600mA (actually -600mA since it's a PNP transistor) so you're good.

Comment: I've learnt a lot today about a lot of stuff thanks to you :) I'll first try connecting a capacitor across Vcc and GND and if that fails, I'll try a switch from a transistor.

Answer (score 0):

According to the data sheet, the supply is supposed to be connected between Vcc and GND, the trigger (which will initiate the generation of the 8 cycle output pulse) is supposed to be connected across TRIG and GND, and the output pulse from the receiver (the width of which will indicate range) should be taken from "Echo" with respect to GND.

So, all you need to do to get a range reading, - after hooking up the power supply as specified in the data sheet - is to trigger the transmitter and to then measure the width of the pulse emanating from the emanating from the "Echo" pin.

Comment: That's not the issue :( I got readings well few days ago and all of sudden it starts freezing and then I found out that if I unplug the Vcc pin and plug it again it's working properly. So that's why I'm thinking about using a switch to use the sonar when only necessary. @Ryan gave a set of good tips and stuff and I'm going to try that :)

Comment: The issue is that if you've got it hooked up right and  it doesn't work the way it's supposed to, then either the device has gone bad or your code is flaky or ??? In any case, toggling Vcc to get it to work for a few seconds isn't really a solution. What you need to do is to find out why it doesn't work the way it's supposed to and then eliminate the problem.